# Joomla Web Links

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to find out how to remove the message "There are no web links in web links category message in Joomla" using Joomla Content Management System. I have also removed the web link using the CMS.

I have already created a website using Joomla. I just need to remove that message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Indunil Sanjeewa

Answer (score 1):

You have to download file: `com_weblinks\views\category\tmpl\default_items.php`

and comment or remove line 32 - 34:

```
<?php if (empty($this->items)) : ?>
    <p> <?php echo JText::_('COM_WEBLINKS_NO_WEBLINKS'); ?></p>
<?php else : ?>
```

Then you have to upload it to directory: `templates\your_template\html\com_weblinks\default_items.php`. ('your_template' is the name of your active template).

Good Luck!

Comment: :) I was expecting to see someone recommending to modify the file in place. That would have been a bad idea!